# Expo Set Wallpaper API

Tags: react-native, expo

Is there any Expo Component or API for change phone wallpaper/Background
I search everywhere but I cant find anything with expo I must Eject to bare react native ?

Answer (score 0):

you should eject to bare react native. use "npx expo prebuild".